# primefaces tab menu only displayed as link

Tags: primefaces

I want to create a xhtml page which contains a dataTable for certain entities, to navigate between the entities i though i could use the TabMenu. But after the implementation the tabMenu menuItems are only showed as simpel links and not how the [primefaces example](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/tabMenu.jsf):
[image: buggy tabMenu]

My code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"  
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"  
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"  
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">  
<h:body>
<h:form>    
    <p:tabMenu activeIndex="0">  
       <p:menuitem value="Customers" url="customerTableView.xhtml" icon="ui-icon-document"/>
       <p:menuitem value="Orders" url="orderTableView.xhtml" icon="ui-icon-document"/>  Vie
    </p:tabMenu>    
</h:form>    
</h:body>
```

Cant find the reason why its not correctly rendered, i also tried diffent browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simply didn't notice that the "head"-tags are missing. Adding them solved the problem.